# enviar algunos input de mi formulario laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, formularios

Buen dia

estoy tratando de hacer un formulario que el cual me registra unos procesos de fabricacion el incovenniente es que una parte de este formulario se registra cada hora entonces la misma secion del formulario se repite varias veces deseo enviar solo esos registros inicialmente pense en hacer un formulario dentro de otro formulario pero investigando vi que esta prohibido entonces la unica forma que se me ocurre es un boton que me envie los datos de los campos que quiero y se resetee despues de enviarlos  se que tengo que usar js pero la verdad no se me ocurre como si alguien tiene una referencia similar agradeceria su ayuda

**blade**

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
<div class="form-group">
<input form="procesos"  id="bt_procesos" type="button" value="guardar" 
  class="btn btn-primary" data-loading-text="Cargando..." name="" >                                  
  </div>
   </div>
```

**controlador**

en el controlador tengo dos coleciones por que un solo formulario se guarda en dos tablas diferentes

```
public function saveform(Request $request) {
    
    $headform = new headform();

    $headform->maquina = $request->maquina;
    $headform->codigo_formulario =$request->codigo_formulario;
    $headform->producto_tamaño=$request->producto_tamaño;
    $headform->hora_inicio=$request->hora_inicio;
    $headform->hora_final=$request->hora_final;
    $headform->fecha_empaque=$request->fecha_empaque;   
    $headform->fecha_vencimiento=$request->fecha_vencimiento;   
    $headform->lote=$request->lote;
    $headform->inspecion_filtros=$request->inspecion_filtros;
    $headform->operario=$request->operario;
    $headform->ingeniero=$request->ingeniero;
    $headform->observaciones=$request->observaciones;


    $headform->save();

    

    $one= new lineone();

    $one->presion_bomba=$request->presion_bomba;

    $one->save();    
}
```

**js**

intente hacer algo para enviar los datos y resetear los campos pero la pagina se me actualiza

```js
$(document).ready(() => {

$('#btn_procesos').on("click", (e) =>  {
  enviar();      
});

});

const enviar = () => {
alert("Entro en la función enviar");
const datos = $("#procesos").serialize();

$.ajax({   
  cache: false,                     
  type: "POST",                 
  url: "{{route('saveform')}}",                    
  data: datos,
  error: function(request, status, error)
  {
    alert("ocurrio un error "+request.responseText)
    console.log(error)
  },
  success: function(data)            
  {
    alert("Hizo el success");
    console.log(data);
  }
});

}
</script>
```

**imagen**

esta desorganizado pero los campos de arriba se llenan una sola vez y los de abajo hasta 8 veces este es el que quiero que al precionar el guardar se reseteen los campos sin actualizar o salirse de la pagina

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

gracias de antemano

Comment: Java != JavaScript. Por otro lado, cuando haces una pregunta es ***Total y Absolutamente Necesario*** que pongas ***TODO EL CÓDIGO RELACIONADO CON TU PREGUNTA***. Por qué? Porque es muy posible que lo que está recargando tu página sea el botón que utilizas para enviar los datos, que seguramente esté declarado con `type=submit`, y ese type ***SIEMPRE*** recarga la página si no lo evitas directamente en JS. Cámbialo por un `type=button` y no se recargará. Y por favor, edita la pregunta y añade **TODO el código *RELEVANTE***. No necesitamos ver cada campo del form, pero si el botón!

Comment: gracias por tu ya edite y efectivamente cambien el submit por el button pero los campos no se resetean

Comment: Es que en ningún momento estás haciendo que se reseteen. Para resetearlos usando jQuery es tan sencillo como `$('.claseDeLosCamposParaResetear).val("");` Si lo pones dentro de la función de `success` los limpiará solo si ha conseguido guardar la info :)